# Is there a recommended way for Solr 3.6 JUnit testing?

Tags: solr, junit, junit4

I wonder if there is any best practice for junit testing of Solr 3.6. I want to automate testing of the Solr schema. Earlier posts mentioned the EmbeddedSolrServer. This class seems to have been abandoned from any version between 1.4 an 3.6. I use Spring 3.0.x and Maven for the project.
The options I considered are:

1. writing a Junit Test Runner
2. put the jetty startup code in the @Before or @BeforeClass method
3. start a solr server in maven (probably not a good option)
4. put some code in the spring test-context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used something similar to what's on [this](http://blog.synyx.de/2011/01/integration-tests-for-your-solr-config/) page to run these kinds of tests, all done with EmbeddedSolrServer on Solr 3.4.0. This is a simple approach, but if you want to automate Solr schema testing, it could be enough and isn't hard to implement.
It basically boils down to:
Adding references to `junit`, `solr-core`, `slf4j-simple`and `servlet-api`to your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- dependencies needed for Solr integration test-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And as an example test case, he adds this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.util.AbstractSolrTestCase;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SolrSearchConfigTest extends AbstractSolrTestCase {

    private SolrServer server;

    @Override
    public String getSchemaFile() {
        return "solr/conf/schema.xml";
    }

    @Override
    public String getSolrConfigFile() {
        return "solr/conf/solrconfig.xml";
    }

    @Before
    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(h.getCoreContainer(), h.getCore().getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatNoResultsAreReturned() throws SolrServerException {
        SolrParams params = new SolrQuery("text that is not found");
        QueryResponse response = server.query(params);
        assertEquals(0L, response.getResults().getNumFound());
    }

    @Test
    public void testThatDocumentIsFound() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
        SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
        document.addField("id", "1");
        document.addField("name", "my name");

        server.add(document);
        server.commit();

        SolrParams params = new SolrQuery("name");
        QueryResponse response = server.query(params);
        assertEquals(1L, response.getResults().getNumFound());
        assertEquals("1", response.getResults().get(0).get("id"));
    }
}
```

**edit:** I haven't used Solr in quite a while, but I think this could still be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I wrote in the question, the EmbeddedSolrServer doesn't exist in Solr 3.6. Unfortunately, this doesn't help much.

Comment: I've just changed my project to Solr 3.6.0 (from 3.4.0) and EmbeddedSolrServer is still there, albeit with one deprecated constructor.
So you should double-check to see if you've got the correct dependencies set up in Maven, as per the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Maven).

Comment: There is a test framework for Solr which I wasn't aware of. By including `org.apache.solr:solr-test-framework` you get som useful base classes for unit testing Solr components. The `EmbeddedSolrServer` is in the solr-core artifact (included as transitive dependency with the test framework).
I included only solrj, therefor the `EmbeddedSolrServer` was missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on it. It doesn't extend AbstractSolrTestCase, just a regular test class.

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.embedded.EmbeddedSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.UpdateResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EmbeddedSolrServerTest {

    private static final int SUCCESS = 0;
    private final String indexLocation = "tomcat7/apps/apache-solr-3.6.0";
    private EmbeddedSolrServer server;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("solr.solr.home", indexLocation);
        CoreContainer coreContainer = new CoreContainer.Initializer().initialize();
        server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, "collection1");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        server.shutdown();
        removeIndexDirectory();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSolrSchema01() throws Exception {
        SolrInputDocument doc1 = new SolrInputDocument();
        doc1.addField("id", "123");
        doc1.addField("something_txt", "super wombat");
        UpdateResponse ur = server.add(doc1);
        assertThat(ur.getStatus(), is(SUCCESS));
        server.commit();

        QueryResponse response1 = server.query(new SolrQuery("*:*"));
        assertThat(response1.getResults().getNumFound(), is(1L));

        QueryResponse response2 = server.query(new SolrQuery("something_txt:*wombat*"));
        assertThat(response2.getResults().getNumFound(), is(1L));
    }

    private void removeIndexDirectory() throws IOException {
        File indexDir = new File(indexLocation, "data/index");
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(indexDir);
    }
}
```

My POM has the following dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <solr.version>3.6.0</solr.version>
    <httpcomponents.version>4.3.2</httpcomponents.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpcomponents.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>${httpcomponents.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've set up a separate project to keep all my Solr config in and run tests against it. The directory structure is:

```
solr-test
|--src
|  |--test
|--tomcat7
`  |--apps
      |--apache-solr-3.6.0
         |--conf
         |--data
            |--index
```

This seems to work well for me. This set up will also let you write tests using HttpSolrServer to test a remote server's schema.

Also, note the `server.commit()` call in the middle of the test. This needs to be there otherwise the Solr transaction isn't complete and the new document won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/moliware/travis-solr for my tests, maybe it's useful for you too.